# firefox complaining about valid json... invisible invalid character?

Tags: php, javascript, special-characters, json

I'm writing a php script that needs to load a 2D array into a js variable as json. First i make the array then use json_encode to turn it into a string. Then I run a small bit of js to get it accessable on the client side. Like so:

```
$sBaseData = Filters::$sFilterBaseTypeData;
$sBaseData = str_replace('\r',' ',$sBaseData);
$sBaseData = str_replace('\n',' ',$sBaseData);
$sBaseData = str_replace('\t',' ',$sBaseData);

echo <<<HTML
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var validation_data = JSON.parse('$sBaseData');
    </script>
HTML;
```

Firefox complains about an unexpected character here:

```
var validation_data = JSON.parse('{"enumeration":{"js":"","msg":""},"date":{"js":" var parts = widget.value.split('-'); var d = new Date(parts[0],parts[1],parts[2]); PASS = (d.getDay()>=1); ","msg":"Invalid date. Please Enter a date in the format: YYYY-MM-DD"},"text":{"js":"","msg":"what did you do?"},"integer":{"js":"if (isNaN(widget.value)) { PASS = false; } else { intVal = parseInt(widget.value); PASS = (widget.value == intVal); } ","msg":"Please enter an integer value"},"decimal":{"js":"PASS = isNaN(widget.value); ","msg":"Please enter a number"},"group":{"js":"","msg":""},"dealer":{"js":"","msg":""}}')
```

I tried using http://jsonlint.com/ to find out which character was at fault but it says it's all valid and wonderful. I replaced some characters that were causing issues, is there anything else I should be replacing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have `'` in your string while you are using `'` to quote the string.

If your json string is valid, you don't need to parse it even. The below will work.

```
echo <<<HTML
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var validation_data = {$sBaseData};
    </script>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Uh...

> ```
> var parts = widget.value.split('-');
> ```

Putting that in a string that uses single quotes will break it. [Use a JSON encoder to output your JavaScript literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10290293/20862).

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is valid but in your js code the simple quote closes the parse function's argument.

Try like this:

```
"date":{"js":" var parts = widget.value.split(\'-\');
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to suggest that the data be changed unless you can be sure that it won't be replaced easily.